# Appropriate Assertion message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, nunit, assert

In a test, I am trying to assert the equality/equivalence of two TextSpan Lists, say as follows:

```
var expectedSpans = new List<TextSpan>()
    {
     new TextSpan { iStartLine = 1, iEndLine = 1, iStartIndex = 1, iEndIndex = 1}
    };

var obtainedSpans = new List<TextSpan>()
    {
     new TextSpan { iStartLine = 2, iEndLine = 2, iStartIndex = 1, iEndIndex = 1}
    };
Assert.That(obtainedSpans, Is.EqualTo(expectedSpans), "Unexpected spans found");
```

And the message I get is:

```
Expected tags were not obtained.
  Expected is <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.TextSpan]> with 1 elements, actual is <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.TextSpan]> with 1 elements
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.TextSpan
  But was:  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.TextSpan
```

How can I get more detailed message, at least showing all values for me to figure out where the equality/equivalence is lost?
The message is not informative in case of equivalence assertion as well.

Comment: Seems like there is no simple way here. I'd suggest you to try to write [a custom constraint](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=customConstraints&r=2.6.2), e.g. inheritance form `NUnit.Framework.Constraints.EqualConstraint` might be suitable. Then you should be able to get the control over the code which generates the assertion message.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedSpans, obtainedSpan, "Unexpected spans found")` for correct list equality assertion.

Btw, two remarks :
- Use `Assert.AreEquals()` instead of `Assert.That(..., IsEqualTo())`
- Always place expected before obtained for readability of assertion failures.

Comment: A few objections: 1) Both `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` and `Assert.That()` do the same comparison and produce exactly the same assertion message when collections are being asserted (checked in NUnit 2.6.2). 2) What is an actual reason to use [classic asserton model](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=classicModel&r=2.6.2) instead of [constraint based assertion model](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6.2)? I don't see any. So the answer appears to be quite irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It's just makes the code more easy to read I think, and that's pretty important.

Comment: In my opinion, Assert.That is easier to read (but it's probably because my team and I are more used to it).